# How to link many client instagram to a facebook page

Tags: instagram, social-networking, facebook-marketing-api

I am going to do instagram ads agency. But I don't know that if I have many clients, how can I link more than one Instagram account to my business facebook page?

Answer (score 1):

I used the app in the link. It does work and helps. http://www.digitaltrends.com/social-media/how-to-manage-multiple-instagram-accounts/